# How do you include alternates in @font-face rules?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I just bought TypeHeist's "Manic" font, and it has 3 WOFF files with alternate characters in it. How do I upload these three, as well as the regular WOFF, using font-face, and have them all be used randomly? Let me know if you need further specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple sources for a single font like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Manic";
  src: url("/path/to/manic-font.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/path/to/manic-font.woff") format("woff");
       ...
}
```

but it is upto the browser to choose a suitable source to use which is supported.
You can read more about the @font-face rule [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)